# Combining Dummy Variable Rows for Factors

Tags: r

I'm trying to create dummy variables for a categorical variable 'person' such that I can see in one row who might have been in the same place on the same day.

Original data 'd':

```
    Date, City, Person,
    2014-11-02, Manchester, Jane
    2014-11-02, Manchester, Tom
    2014-11-15, London, Susan
    2014-11-16, London, Harry
    2014-11-16, Birmingham, Tom
    2014-12-01, Birmingham, Susan
    2014-12-01, Birmingham, Jane
```

What I'd like to accomplish:

```
    Date, City, Tom, Harry, Susan, Jane
     2014-11-02, Manchester, 1, 0, 0, 1
     2014-11-15, London, 0, 0, 1, 0
     2014-11-16, London, 0, 1, 0, 1
     2014-11-16, Birmingham, 1, 0, 0, 0
     2014-12-01, Birmingham, 0, 0, 1, 1
```

I've tried:

```
    for(level in unique(d$person)){
    d[paste("Person", level, sep = "_")]
    <-      ifelse(d$Person == level, 1, 0)
    }
```

But I get individual rows per observation and not the consolidation of when the same person is in the same city on the same day into a single row.

Comment: Try with `dcast` i.e. `library(data.table);dcast(setDT(df1), Date + City ~Person, length)`

Comment: Crikey, that's simple and works great.  Thank you.

Comment: A simple alternative might also be the built in `model.matrix`.